# Magento 2 Search terms shows Chinese word

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento2

We have developed a Magento 2 site. For last few weeks search term in admin panel shows **Chinese words** as below

1. 바카라사이트¶ ( ―▷ 79ASK，CoM ◁― ) ¶33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노
2. 大奖娱乐HB老虎机送彩金www.djyl18.com
3. 趣拍娱乐MG老虎机开户 www.qpyl18.com
4. 大奖老虎机优惠红利 Q82019309.com.com

Searches term in Magento admin panel

[image]

Please, can anyone explain why the Chinese word exists in Magento search term? help me to solve the issue?

Thank You
pari.J

Comment: Number 1. is Korean ;-) Probably spam bots that used the front-end search.